# could not locate cfg.xml for hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

i am trying to connect test a normal insertion code into mysql database using hibernate and getting error for this, i write the exception details below.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/home/controller/Documents/sts_work/webtracker/src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at testHBConnection.main(testHBConnection.java:12)
```

and my java file for test is

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.ar.entity.Student;

public class testHBConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().configure("/home/controller/Documents/sts_work/webtracker/src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses=sf.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            Student stu= new Student("","name");

            ses.beginTransaction();
            ses.save(stu);

            ses.getTransaction().commit();

        }
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception "+e);

}
        finally{


        }

    }

}
```

and i linked here my project structure below

where Student is the pojo file releted to database table
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure, hibernate.cfg.xml is present in the absolute location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use this path

```
/home/controller/Documents/sts_work/webtracker/src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

because of `configure()` method waits for class path resource (loaded by a classloader) or URL.

Better to use a resource, of course. So, if you have `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the `src/main/java/` you don't need to specify the path to it at all:

```
new Configuration().configure()
```

There is one tricky thing. It will work when you build a jar, for example and run it. if you will want to run application from the IDE, in some cases, better to check that `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the class path in the project configuration.

But the more professional way put `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the `resources`folder, if you use Maven or gradle, for example.

Comment: the problem is solved after relocated cfg.xml file to src/main/java

Comment: @AllahRakha It was already be there. No? `src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: no,i relocated it at src/main/java/ , and now it working